# update a column with the latest hiredate of an employee

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

I have an employee status history table.

[image: EmployeeSTatusHistory]

I need to create one more column that should copy the min(EffectiveStartDate) on each row till the employee is rehired. I need to get the length of service of the employee where the date will be passed by UI.

[image: NewCOlumn HireRehireDate]

How can i achieve in SQL server 2014

Comment: Just wanted to check back and see if the answer I gave was clear enough, or if you had any further questions on it. If the answer is what you were looking for, go ahead and accept the answer (check mark by the answer) to let others that stumble on this question later that it was in fact the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has a few assumptions.

**Assumptions**

1. The data set is only for one Employee at a time. If it is not,
   and there is another column, such as `EmployeeID`, then you will
   want to specify that in a `partition by` clause inside the `over`
   clause where my comments denote that.
2. That the `EmployeeStatusCatalog` values have the below meanings:

   - A: Active
   - L: Leave (of Absence)
   - I: Inactive
3. That a "Hire" or "Rehire" transaction is considered to happen
   either at initial `A` status, or after an `I` status has ended.

**Sample Data Setup**

Did not include the `EmployeeStatusId` column, as my assumption is that it is not relevant to creating the expected outcome.

```
declare @employee table 
    (
        EffectiveStartDate date not null
        , EffectiveEndDate date not null
        , EmployeeStatusCatalog char(1) not null
    )

insert into @employee
    values ('2008-02-29', '2016-05-31', 'A')
         , ('2016-06-01', '2016-06-30', 'A')
         , ('2016-07-01', '2016-07-30', 'L')
         , ('2016-07-31', '2016-09-02', 'A')
         , ('2016-09-03', '2016-10-09', 'I')
         , ('2016-10-10', '2016-11-01', 'A')
         , ('2016-11-02', '2016-12-02', 'L')
         , ('2016-12-03', '2016-12-05', 'I')
         , ('2016-12-06', '2016-12-06', 'A')
         , ('2016-12-07', '2017-01-01', 'L')
         , ('2017-01-02', '9999-12-31', 'A')
```

**Answer**

As you may or may not know, this is a classic [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) scenario. Where each segment between Hire/Rehire dates is an island (no gaps in this example).

I used a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to move the `I` status forward one row (via [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function), and then get the running count of the number of `I` rows to give each island a "ID" number.

After that, used a `min` function, while partitioning by the island number, to determine the minimum `EffectiveStartDate` for each island.

```
; with inactive_dts as
    (
        --move the I status forward one row
        select e.EffectiveStartDate
        , e.EffectiveEndDate
        , e.EmployeeStatusCatalog
        , lag(e.EmployeeStatusCatalog, 1, 'A') over (/*partion by here*/ order by e.EffectiveStartDate asc) as prev_status
        from @employee as e 
        where 1=1
    )
    , active_island_nbr as 
    (
        --get the running count of the number of I rows
        select a.EffectiveStartDate
        , a.EffectiveEndDate
        , a.EmployeeStatusCatalog
        , a.prev_status
        , sum(case a.prev_status when 'I' then 1 else 0 end) over (/*partition by here*/ order by a.EffectiveStartDate asc) as ActiveIslandNbr
        from inactive_dts as a  
    )
select min(a.EffectiveStartDate) over (partition by a.ActiveIslandNbr) as HireRehireDate
, a.EffectiveStartDate
, a.EffectiveEndDate
, a.EmployeeStatusCatalog
from active_island_nbr as a
```

**Results**

```
HireRehireDate  EffectiveStartDate  EffectiveEndDate  EmployeeStatusCatalog
2008-02-29      2008-02-29          2016-05-31        A
2008-02-29      2016-06-01          2016-06-30        A
2008-02-29      2016-07-01          2016-07-30        L
2008-02-29      2016-07-31          2016-09-02        A
2008-02-29      2016-09-03          2016-10-09        I
2016-10-10      2016-10-10          2016-11-01        A
2016-10-10      2016-11-02          2016-12-02        L
2016-10-10      2016-12-03          2016-12-05        I
2016-12-06      2016-12-06          2016-12-06        A
2016-12-06      2016-12-07          2017-01-01        L
2016-12-06      2017-01-02          9999-12-31        A
```